# How can I give an Android app a Russian title

Tags: android, package-name

I am using Android Studio to make an app that will be in Russian. I don't have any problems with using Russian font in the app itself, but how can I create an app with a Russian title? I am creating a New Project, and then when I try to type Russian into the Application Name text box I get an error message: "Invalid package name: Package segments must be of non-zero length".

Answer (score 2):

yes can give the name of the app in russian language but not package names.. If you want to change only title then you can go through this link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Great. Thanks Khushvinder.

Answer (score 0):

Application id (package name) is auto generated using the application name provided in new project wizard. (unless you manually change it after entering the application name) If you are entering non English characters (Russian in your case) for application name. You'll need to check and change the application I'd (package name) to use only English characters. Of is just below the application name in the new project wizard.